# Nginx Ingress controller throwing 400 Bad Request error

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have set up the `Nginx-Ingress` controller as per the documentation ([Installation guide](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/))and followed the steps using the example provided. When I try to access the service using the `curl` command, I am getting a `400`  Bad request. When I look at the logs of the `nginx-ingress` pod, I am not seeing any error. I have attached the logs for reference. I am finding difficult to troubleshoot the issue. Where

```
fetch the pods from the nginx-ingress namespace
$ kubectl get po -n nginx-ingress
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coffee-7c45f487fd-965dq          1/1     Running   0          46m
coffee-7c45f487fd-bncz5          1/1     Running   0          46m
nginx-ingress-7f4b784f79-7k4q6   1/1     Running   0          48m
tea-7769bdf646-g559m             1/1     Running   0          46m
tea-7769bdf646-hlr5j             1/1     Running   0          46m
tea-7769bdf646-p5hp8             1/1     Running   0          46m

making the request. I have set up the DNS record in the /etc/hosts file
$ curl -vv http://cafe.example.com/coffee
GET /coffee HTTP/1.1
> Host: cafe.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.17.10
< Date: Mon, 11 May 2020 17:36:31 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 158
< Connection: close

checking the logs after the curl request
$ kubectl logs -n nginx-ingress nginx-ingress-7f 4b784f79-7k4q6

100.96.1.1 - - [11/May/2020:17:31:48 +0000] "PROXY TCP4 172.20.61.112 172.20.61.112 8340 32579" 400 158 "-" "-" "-"
100.96.1.1 - - [11/May/2020:17:31:51 +0000] "PROXY TCP4 172.20.81.142 172.20.81.142 40392 32579" 400 158 "-" "-" "-"
100.96.1.1 - - [11/May/2020:17:31:58 +0000] "PROXY TCP4 172.20.61.112 172.20.61.112 8348 32579" 400 158 "-" "-" "-"
100.96.1.1 - - [11/May/2020:17:32:01 +0000] "PROXY TCP4 172.20.81.142 172.20.81.142 40408 32579" 400 158 "-" "-" "-"
100.96.1.1 - - [11/May/2020:17:32:08 +0000] "PROXY TCP4 172.20.61.112 172.20.61.112 8360 32579" 400 158 "-" "-" "-"
100.96.1.1 - - [11/May/2020:17:32:11 +0000] "PROXY TCP4 172.20.81.142 172.20.81.142 40414 32579" 400 158 "-" "-" "-"
100.96.1.1 - - [11/May/2020:17:32:18 +0000] "PROXY TCP4 3.6.94.242 172.20.81.142 35790 80" 400 158 "-" "-" "-"
100.96.1.1 - - [11/May/2020:17:32:18 +0000] "PROXY TCP4 172.20.61.112 172.20.61.112 8366 32579" 400 158 "-" "-" "-"
100.96.1.1 - - [11/May/2020:17:32:21 +0000] "PROXY TCP4 172.20.81.142 172.20.81.142 40422 32579" 400 158 "-" "-" "-"
```

Comment: Hi, what k8s version do You use? Also what platform/infrastructure do You use? And which cluster deployment method did You use?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue after adding the following annotations.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: true
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: true
```

Comment: Thank you!. This was the problem on my AKS... no idea why this happen and the error was not clear.

Comment: Was getting an error of "json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.annotations of type string". Should these not be strings instead?